# How to get default application for an action

Tags: android

How can I determine which application is the default application for a certain action? For example I want to know which application is used for making calls or receiving text messages. Is there any way to find out which application is set as default programmatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PackageManager.resolveActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#resolveActivity%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) does something along the lines of what you're looking for. From the official docs:

> Determine the best action to perform for a given Intent. This is how
> resolveActivity(PackageManager) finds an activity if a class has not
> been explicitly specified.

And here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8626723/645270):

```
Intent i = (new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com")));
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
final ResolveInfo mInfo = pm.resolveActivity(i, 0);
Toast.makeText(
    context, 
    pm.getApplicationLabel(mInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo),
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
).show();
```

Note that the return value is somewhat fuzzy:

> Returns a ResolveInfo containing the final activity intent that was
> determined to be the best action. Returns null if no matching activity
> was found. If multiple matching activities are found and there is no
> default set returns a ResolveInfo containing something else, such as
> the activity resolver.

Comment: I used ACTION_DIAL and was able to get the packageName of the dialer app. Thank you very much. Any idea how to find out which app is chosen as default SMS app?

Comment: You mean some specific action? Maybe ACTION_SENDTO, but I'm just guessing :) Glad I could help.

Comment: I tried ACTION_SENDTO but it's only for sending emails as far as I know.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2372665/645270) help? It uses `setData` on the intent ACTION_VIEW.

Comment: Why if I use Intent i = (new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:0123456789"))) or Intent i = (new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL)) is result allways System Android?

Comment: Did you try adding MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY flag which insures to return the same activity as startActivity would?

Answer (score 1):

Use Intent Filters and resolveActivity().

[From Android's documentation on Intent Filters:](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textMessage);
sendIntent.setType(HTTP.PLAIN_TEXT_TYPE); // "text/plain" MIME type

ComponentName compName = sendIntent.resolveActivity();
```

[And here's the documentation on ComponentName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html)

Comment: Using your example I get "android" as compName.getPackageName(). Doesn't seem to work. Any idea?