# How to get default camera and gallery package info?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera, android-gallery

I want to create a dialog which would let users to select either camera or gallery to pick an image from.
Each item in the dialog needs an icon and an image.
How can I get those for the default camera and gallery?

**Update**

I'm currently getting it like this

```
val galleryIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).apply {
    setType("image/*")
    addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, arrayOf("image/jpeg", "image/png"))
}
val galleryResInfo = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(galleryIntent, 0)[0]
```

Then in the dialog recycler view holder I can get the icon and name like this

```
val packageManager = holder.appName.context.packageManager
holder.appIcon.setImageDrawable(app.resolveInfo.loadIcon(packageManager))
holder.appName.setText(app.resolveInfo.loadLabel(packageManager))
```

Aren't there a better solution?

Comment: as you  were not happy with the two answers it is unclear what you want to achieve. If you want to launch the Camera or the Gallery with two buttons, you can provide your own two icons for that and use the intents from the answers. If you need the Applications itself, you can also go with that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23172341/1505074

Comment: packageManager.resolveActivity from the answer at that link was exactly what I was looking for. The only thing which is missing from there is the MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY flag which insures to return the same activity as startActivity would. Thank you, Christian!

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting the two intents

```
Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
```

with the corresponding parameters separately but without a chooser, Android will open the default App for that if any is selected.

Comment: The question is about getting package info, not intent.

Answer (score 0):

Gallery Intent

```
Intent intent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
```

Camera Intent

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

Comment: The question is about getting package info, not intent.