# Get packagename of stock messaging app

Tags: android, messenger, package-name

my app needs to get the packagename of the stock messaging app. But because every provider has got it's own I dont really know how to solve this.

My only idea would be to check every packagename on runtime to get the correct one.

Has anyone a better idea or a list of packagenames i could use?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What if the user does not use the "stock messaging app", but uses another one that they got from the Play Store or elsewhere?

Comment: Try taking a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8626723/950427

Comment: I've got a question for you. If you have the package name of the stock messaging app, why do you want it?

Comment: Send the user to the applications details of the app

Comment: Solved it with the list....