# How to get default sms,gallery,call,contacts and browser app and package name in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, homescreen

I am creating an home replacement app for android(Launcher) and I want to place the sms , call, contacts ,gallery and browser apps in the home screen. How can I know the package name for them.

If the user is using a custom contact app as the default one , I need to get the package name of that one and not the android contact app.

How can I achieve this?Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code to get `Intent` to those thing. The problomatic one is the `SMS` one.

For sms:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                String defaultSmsPackageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(ctx);
                Intent lunchIntent;
                if (defaultSmsPackageName != null) {
                    launchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(defaultSmsPackageName);
                } else {
                    String SMS_MIME_TYPE = "vnd.android-dir/mms-sms";
                    launchIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    launchIntent.setType(SMS_MIME_TYPE);
                }
            } else {
                String SMS_MIME_TYPE = "vnd.android-dir/mms-sms";
                launchIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                launchIntent.setType(SMS_MIME_TYPE);
            }
```

For call:

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
```

For browser:

```
Intent intent;
Intent queryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
                ActivityInfo af = queryIntent.resolveActivityInfo(pm, 0);
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.setClassName(af.packageName, af.name);
```

For photos:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("content://media/internal/images/media"));
                try {
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException eee){
                    try {
                        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setType(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.CONTENT_TYPE);
                    } catch (Exception err){
                        Toast.makeText(context, "This app not supported in your device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Thanks , but how will I get the default app name , its image uri and its package name from this? Will I get it by using PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
final ResolveInfo mInfo = pm.resolveActivity(intent, 0);

Comment: @yshahak: How about voice app. Let see my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40500143/how-to-get-default-device-assistance-app-in-android-by-code

Answer (score 1):

You could try getting the default launch activity for a specific `Intent`, for example for SMS you do an `Intent` with an `sms:`-URI, and from there check the 'default'-Activity its launching, on the way getting its package name and other details.

[Get Preferred/Default app on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626421/get-preferred-default-app-on-android)