# How to get default device assistance app in android by code?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-settings, google-voice

my phone installed two voice searches: google app and S-voice app. The default app is S-voice app as figure bellow. My question is that how can we get the default voice application using programmingcally in Android 6.0. Thank you in advance

[image]

This is what I did

```
private boolean isMyAppLauncherDefault(String myPackageName) {
    final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);

    List<IntentFilter> filters = new ArrayList<IntentFilter>();
    filters.add(filter);
    List<ComponentName> activities = new ArrayList<ComponentName>();
    final PackageManager packageManager = (PackageManager) getPackageManager();

    packageManager.getPreferredActivities(filters, activities, null);
    for (ComponentName activity : activities) {

        Log.d(TAG,"======packet default:==="+activity.getPackageName());
    }
    for (ComponentName activity : activities) {

        if (myPackageName.equals(activity.getPackageName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The above function is alway return true when my input is `com.samsung.voiceserviceplatform`. In other hands, the default app always returns `com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox` (indicates google voice)

Comment: Do you need to initiate Google App pro-grammatically?

Comment: No Sir, I just need to turn on google or svoice app from default setting. For example, if my default setting is svoice, i will launch svoice. If my default voice setting is google voice, I will call Google voice

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`DefaultAssistPreference`](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/applications/DefaultAssistPreference.java#L175) uses an hidden method of [`AssistUtils`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/app/AssistUtils.java#L135-L157) to retrieve the current Assist. You can use the same method using reflection:

```
public ComponentName getCurrentAssistWithReflection(Context context) {
    try {
        Method myUserIdMethod = UserHandle.class.getDeclaredMethod("myUserId");
        myUserIdMethod.setAccessible(true);
        Integer userId = (Integer) myUserIdMethod.invoke(null);

        if (userId != null) {
            Constructor constructor = Class.forName("com.android.internal.app.AssistUtils").getConstructor(Context.class);
            Object assistUtils = constructor.newInstance(context);

            Method getAssistComponentForUserMethod = assistUtils.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getAssistComponentForUser", int.class);
            getAssistComponentForUserMethod.setAccessible(true);
            return (ComponentName) getAssistComponentForUserMethod.invoke(assistUtils, userId);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

If you don't want to use reflection you can directly check the system settings:

```
public ComponentName getCurrentAssist(Context context) {
    final String setting = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), "assistant");

    if (setting != null) {
        return ComponentName.unflattenFromString(setting);
    }

    return null;
}
```

It is the same setting that reads `AssistUtils`, but `AssistUtils` has also a [fallback](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/app/AssistUtils.java#L142-L155) if the setting is not valid.

Comment: Thank you. From your answer, I try to print the list of default apps in the assistant, but it does not work. I used the code: `ComponentName activity=getCurrentAssistWithReflection(getApplicationContext());
        Log.d("TAG","======packet default:==="+activity.getPackageName());`

Comment: Is this code inside a try block or your app crash when you execute you code? Because if `getCurrentAssistWithReflection` doesn't work it returns null and you can't `getPackageName` of a null instance.

Comment: I will try it on my real device. I think it will not work on my emulator. In additions, I have two apps in the assistant. How can I list those apps? The above script only can show one app.

Comment: It returns the default application, it doesn't returns a list. You question is pretty clear to me: `how can we get the default voice application using programmingcally in Android 6.0`. You didn't ask for the list of assistant apps.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. It only returns one default app. I will test on my real device and confirm it to you

Comment: I confirmed that your code `getCurrentAssistWithReflection` worked well as my expected. I tested it on my real device. The second method `getCurrentAssist` does not work. However, the first method is enough for me. Do you think your first method is also work in Android L ? Thanks

Comment: No, `AssistUtils` is added in Android M, it isn't available in Android L

Comment: Do you know any method to get default voice application in Android L? Just addition question. In android L, you can see it by going to Task Management (Long Home button press)> Default

Comment: @MattiaMaestrini no reflection method doesn't work on Android O

Comment: @LiorIluz Like so many things in Android, the way to handle that would be to call `getCurrentAssist` and fall back to `getCurrentAssistWithReflection` so you handle every available scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```

Comment: I used it before but it always call google voice, instead off my default voice setting

Comment: Thanks it worked now. It only worked in 5.0, instead of 6.0. Do you know why?

Comment: I tested again. The above function is not stable. It will show me an option for choosing between Svoice and Google voice. However, if i not choose any app. it will default google and then when i turn on the intent, the google voice sometimes nothing to show. I used the code for google `                  intent.setClassName("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox",                                "com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.VoiceSearchActivity");`

Comment: Sorry. I cannot accept your answer because it cannot solve my issue. I test again in the Android L and meet above issue. The issue is that when I used your code, the google voice or s-voice sometimes do not turn on. I am calling above function in a service.

Answer (score 0):

I try answer from [Mattia Maestrini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40566276/4754366), it did work if returned component is an activity, like

```
ComponentInfo{com.sec.android.app.sbrowser/com.sec.android.app.sbrowser.SBrowserMainActivity}
```

but if the component is a service, I meet following problem

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { 
act=android.intent.action.ASSIST cmp=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.voiceinteraction.GsaVoiceInteractionService launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } } without permission android.permission.BIND_VOICE_INTERACTION
```

and I do add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_VOICE_INTERACTION"/>
```

in Manifest file.

At last I use method in Activity.java

```
public boolean showAssist(Bundle args)
```

It's added from **Android M** and it could start assistant service successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is seaching a quick kotlin version for that:

```
fun getCurrentlySelectedDefaultAssistant(context: Context): ComponentName? =
    Settings.Secure.getString(context.contentResolver, "assistant").let { assistantIdentifier ->
        if (assistantIdentifier.isNotEmpty()) {
            ComponentName.unflattenFromString(assistantIdentifier)
        } else {
            null
        }
    }
```

Thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40566276/371749
Just re-written.